# trying to make decimal to binary converter using recursion in c

Tags: c, recursion, binary, converters

and i need to make a decimal to binery converter in c with recursion 
but  the output is wrong
ex decimal = 22,  correct binary = 10110, output = 01101

so this is the code that i came up with

```
#include <stdio.h>

int biner (int a){


    if (a == 1)
    return 1;

    else if (a % 2 == 1)
    {
    printf ("1");
    return biner (a / 2);
    }


    else
    {
    printf ("0");
    return biner (a / 2);
    }



}


int main () {
    int a;
    printf ("Masukan angka ");
    scanf ("%d", &a);


    printf ("%d", biner (a));



}
```

which part do i need to change
thanks in advance

Comment: Your program computes and displays the result in reverse.

Comment: i  already put the input, output, and expected before the code.

Comment: Please explain the idea of your code. Do you want to print while recursing? Do you want to return something which is then printed? You seem to be trying to do both. The first step is to decide and clean this up. Then a solution can be proposed. I propose to change your code to not return anything and only print while recursing. I.e. make a void function. Do not return. Do not try to print the return of biner().

Comment: Please try and show the output for all values 0 to 31. You will notice that some of them are not even matching the reverse pattern. Make sure that all paths of all `if`s print something.

Answer (score 1):

OP's code output is in the wrong order as it needs to recurse before printing to print the most significant digits first.

Instead of

```
printf ("1");   // prints least significant digit
biner (a / 2);  // prints most significant digits
```

More like

```
biner (a / 2);  // prints most significant digits
printf ("1");   // prints least significant digit
```

---

There really is no need to return a value, let `biner()` can do all printing.

As code is not attempting to print a *sign*, might as well use `unsigned a`.

OP's code recurses endlessly if `a == 0`.  Only recurse if `a >= 1`.  ( a binary digit exist to the left.)

With `d` as 0 or 1, The binary digit to print can use `putchar('0' + d)`

Suggested simplification:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void biner(unsigned a) {
  if (a > 1) {   // Do binary digits exist to the left?
    biner(a/2);  // Print them.
  }
  putchar('0' + a%2);  // Now print the least significant digit.
}

int main(void) {
  unsigned a;
  printf("Masukan angka ");
  scanf("%u", &a);

  biner(a);
  putchar('\n');
}
```